# How to retain UITextField text when navigating to different view controller and returning back to first view controller?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a login page having 3 textfield in my first view as i navigate to different view and return back to my first view (i.e i am loggin in application and then logging out of that).I want my 2 textfield to retain its value and I should be able to log in again.
Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` for the same in which you can add two objects and get the values whenever you come to that view and then you can display the same.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textUserName.text forKey:@"UserName"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textPassword.text forKey:@"Password"];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    textUserName.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  objectForKey:@"UserName"];
    textPassword.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  objectForKey:@"Password"]
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: can you give some example how to do this ?

Comment: but its showing username and password on opening of application also.. and i want when user logout from app and comes to first view only then it should be visible.