# call storyboard and xib in same viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, xib

I don't know how to load my page as it is, When i press back button. I have two type of pages storyboard and xib. Which display all information, When i click go button it will taken to new page. All these working good, But my problem is when i press back button i need my storyboard and xib file should be display in same view. When i run my app it display only storyboard page xib didn't load.

Thanks for advance here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    Recharge *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Recharge"];
    [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
    self.recharge = [[mobileViewcontroller alloc]init];
    self.recharge.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,100, 400, 400);
    [self addChildViewController:self.recharge];
    [self.view addSubview:self.recharge.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    Recharge *rechargeView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Recharge"];
    [self presentViewController:rechargeView animated:YES completion:nil];

    self.recharge = [[mobileViewcontroller alloc]init];
    self.recharge.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,100, 400, 400);
    [rechargeView addChildViewController:self.recharge];
    [rechargeView.view addSubview:self.recharge.view];
}
```

And it will work.

As you are adding your `mobileViewcontroller` view on your `current viewController` which is not visible to user, instead you should add your `mobileViewcontroller` to the the `recharge viewController` which is in hierarchy and visible to user.

Comment: really super bro its worked thank u so much for ur help...:) :) and one more small request in that page i have entered some fields i want to restore the same value when i press back button

Comment: You welcome. So you want to restore values at what page?

Comment: in MobileViewController page i.e self.recharge = [[mobileViewcontroller alloc]init];

Comment: in MobileViewController i have two textField callled Phone Number and amount both the field contains some value i need to restore the same value when i call again that same page

Comment: For that either do not simplest way is just do not create your mobileviewcontroller object again and again. apply a check at back button action if(!self.recharge){ self.recharge = [[mobileViewcontroller alloc]init]; } so if there is already an object it will not create a new one and use the old one

Comment: or save your values in nsuser defaults and use them whenever need.

Comment: ok bro very thank u for ur suggestion i keep ur words and work if i struck anywhere i comment again

Comment: c this link the same problem iam facing  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131762/how-to-retain-uitextfield-text-when-navigating-to-different-view-controller-and

Comment: what problem you are facing by using user defaults?

Comment: plz check this question i have posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650865/how-to-retain-my-uitextfield-values-in-viewcontroller-when-i-calling?noredirect=1#comment41905570_26650865

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `Recharge` is the view controller from the storyboard and `mobileViewController` is the view controller from the xib.

You're calling the wrong constructor to load `mobileViewController`. You need to use `(instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle` to load it with a xib file. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:

Comment: can u write code to load my storyboard and xib file together

Comment: Uh, I even gave you the init method to call. It's pretty straight forward. Replace `self.recharge = [[mobileViewcontroller alloc]init];` with `self.recharge = [[mobileViewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"yournibname.xib" bundle:nil];`

Comment: i hav main storyboard it contains tableview in that same viewcontroller i add subview of xib file to display as same viewcontroller,upto these steps its working good but when i cleck back button need to display the view as it is

Comment: iam tried Recharge *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Recharge"];
        [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
  
        self.mobileView = [[mobileViewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"mobileViewcontroller.xib" bundle:nil];
        self.mobileView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,100, 400, 400);
        [self addChildViewController:self.mobileView];
        [self.view addSubview:self.mobileView.view];

Answer (score 0):

when ever you call new viewcontroller with passing somthing you have do code like this put all code before[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];

try this:

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender 
  {

  Recharge *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Recharge"];

  self.recharge = [[mobileViewcontroller alloc]init];

  self.recharge.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,100, 400, 400);

  [view addChildViewController:self.recharge];

  [view addSubview:self.recharge.view];

  [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];

  }

Comment: what u did is same what i did its not worked anyways thanks for ur time for this reply i got output from Ihulk