# how to retain my uitextfield values in viewController when i calling?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, retain, nscoding

I have a main page having 3 textfield in my first view as i navigate to different view and return back to my first view (i.e after i enter all the values i moving to next page).I want my 3 textfield to retain its value when i go back to my main page here my sample code :

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *mobile = MobileNum.text;
 [defaults setObject:mobile forKey:self.MobileNum.text];
 NSString *amountText = amount.text;
 [defaults setObject:amountText forKey:self.amount.text];
 [defaults synchronize];
 NSString *temp = [defaults objectForKey:self.MobileNum.text];
 NSString *temp1 = [defaults objectForKey:self.amount.text];
 NSLog(@"%@ %@",temp,temp1);
```

Comment: Please share the output of this `NSLog` also.

Comment: now what the problem u meet

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik simple bro i just need all my textfield value should retain for example in mobile Number textfield i enter value like :0991236547 and in amount text 10 after that iam moving to second page.when i go back to my previous page the mobile number and amount textfield should have values what i have entered previously

Comment: can u show ur result  NSLog(@"%@ %@",temp,temp1);

Comment: iam getting 8552123654 12

Comment: iam getting value in nslog but its not retain in textfield

Comment: if you are able to access them then just simply put them in your text field inside the viewwillappear method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at you viewWillDisappear method store the defaults like.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *mobile = MobileNum.text;
 [defaults setObject:mobile forKey:@"mobileNumber"];
 NSString *amountText = amount.text;
 [defaults setObject:amountText forKey:@"amount"];
 [defaults synchronize];
```

again at your viewWillAppear method retrieve the values like.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   if ([[defaults valueForKey:@"mobileNumber"] length]>0){
     MobileNum.text=[defaults valueForKey:@"mobileNumber"];
   }
 else {
     MobileNum.text=@"";
  }
  if ([[defaults valueForKey:@"amount"] length]>0) {
    amount.text=[defaults valueForKey:@"amount"];
   }
 else {
    amount.text=@"";
  }
```

it will work.

Comment: its worked fine but one small change bro instead of viewWillDisappear and viewWillAppear method i tryed viewDidDisappear and viewDidAppear method. u really a rockstar bro in ios Hats of to u :)